# The boolean expression from a circuit

Tags: digital-logic, circuit-design, boolean-algebra

Would the final boolean expression to the circuit be right? Or do I have to multiply the brackets b(c*d)' out to bc' + bd'

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fEPOIP.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Edit: My new idea would be:

(a'+b)*(bc'+bd') = a'bc'+a'bd'+bbc' + bbd' = a'bc' + a'bd' + bc' + bd'

Comment: Does + really mean "NOR?"

Comment: Oh, sorry, I will edit sth. in the picture.

Comment: Now, there should be the right gate.

Comment: Is the expression to the circuit now right?

Comment: How do you get bc' + bd' out of b(c*d)'?  For that fact, how do you  figure to get that b out of (a'+b)?  Wouldn't you have to do something with the a'?

Comment: How do you get bc' + bd' out of b(c*d)'? : By multplying the brackets out

Comment: But then where's the rest of it?

Comment: So you would recommend to factorise b ?:  b ( a' + c'd')?

Comment: I'm saying that if you multiply things out to get b(c*d)' , then you ought to have something with a'(some stuff) as well, and that'll be + b(c*d)' .  And, will that be simpler (or can it be simplified to something simpler) than your current result?

Comment: (a'+b)*(bc'+bd') = a'bc'+a'bd'+bbc' + bbd' = a'bc' + a'bd' + bc' + bd' , do you mean this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using *De Morgan's theorem*: `(A*B)' = A' + B'`

The output of AND3 gate in the image should be **`(a'+b)*(b*(c'+d'))`** instead of **`(a'+b)*(b*(c'*d'))`**

Which is how I assume you arrived at the edit part of your question. Now expanding the above expression, you get:

`a'bc' + a'bd' + bc' + bd'`

The above expression can be further simplified by grouping the terms:

`bc'(a'+1) + bd'(a'+1)`

And further using the *Annulment law of Boolean Algebra*, you get:

`b (c' + d')` as your final simplified expression.

Please let me know if this answered your question.

Comment: Can I also do this ?: (a'+b)*(bc' + bd') = a'bc' + a'bd' + bbc' + bbd' (using here the idempotence law) = a'bc' + a'bd' + bc' + bd' (using here again the idempotence law) = bc' + bd' + bc' + bd' (using again the idempotence law) = bc' + bd' = b ( c'+d') ?

Comment: The first step is applying distributive law not idempotent law. And the second time your simplification idempotence law isn't right. a'bc' + a'bd' + bc' + bd' cannot become bc' + bd' + bc' + bd' (don't understand how a' terms were directly removed). The only way from the second step I see is to use the simplification I captured in the answer.

Comment: a'bc' + a'bd' + bc' + bd' cannot become bc' + bd' + bc' + bd' (don't understand how a' terms were directly removed).: a' + a' = a', thought i could do it as well with a' + a' = 0

Comment: but it seems to be there is no other way than using the annulment law in the last step, i did not know this law before

Comment: @lightsodium a' + a' = a' not 0. Also you can't apply idempotent law directly because there are bc'/bd' terms associated with a'. An easy way to determine if any simplification is correct is to apply a set of values and check if the simplified and original expressions yield the same answer. Try a=1 b=1 c=d=0 in your case and it does not yield the same final logic state.

Comment: but the simplified expression does not have the same truth table as the original expression anymore, right? because the simplified one is depending on the variables b,c,d and the original one on a,b,c,d

Comment: @lightsodium In your truth table, the optimised variables basically become *X* or don't care(either 0 or 1 does not affect output) as you may have encountered in examples. But the output expression value needs to still hold true.